# "She doesn't like fruit" vs. "she doesn't like fruits"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

In the following context, which do you use and why?

> Helen doesn't eat apples or bananas. She doesn't like [fruit/fruits].

I think it is *fruit* but I'm having a hard time explaining to myself why it isn't *fruits*. What is the reason?

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

*Fruit* is usually noncountable, and that’s what it is in your example. It is, however, used as a countable noun when it used in the plural to describe individual pieces or different kinds of fruit, as in  *fruits of the forest*.

Answer (score 1):

She doesn't like *fruit* in general. She can go to the grocers, where there lots of different *fruits* but it's all in vain because she dislikes *fruit*.

I thought [this](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-when-is-it-ok-to-use-fruits-and-food-in-the-plural-form/) was a nice explanation of the matter.